# What are the two 'hidden' achievements, and how do I get them?

Tags: achievements, browser-quest

In [BrowserQuest](http://browserquest.mozilla.org/), the achievements list includes 2 that are denoted only as **??? /  ???**

[image: cheevos]

I've already defeated the 'final boss' and completed all of the other achievements (Ignore the 16/20 there, the 2 I'm missing amount to 'get hit a lot of times').

What are these last two medals, and how do I get them?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One of them is in the cave behind three ogres and four pillars. always take the left most door (on the top or bottom, even if you just came through it.)

The other one is in town, on the far right. Go through the portal (the sparkly bridge thingy), wait for the item to spawn, interact with it.

Comment: #19 in the cave:
Up left
Up middle
Up left
Down left

Comment: in the 4 pillars cave. Left UP, left UP, left DOWN. You will get the "Rickroll'd - Take some singing lessons" badge. Screen: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14210264/screens/browserquest.mozilla.org.rickrolld-badge.png

Answer (score 8):

One of them is "For Science"
You must get a Cake on the right side of village
(Reference to Portal)

Comment: It's a cake....

Comment: And I bet I know exactly where too... I saw the portals, but there was nothing there...

Comment: it's a lie, and we knows it :)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz You should just wait for it to reappear.

Comment: @Bora Yeah, I did as soon as I saw this.

Answer (score 8):

The other one, I wont tell the name, is in the forest, in a cave behind three ogers and 4 stone pillars.

Answer (score 3):

When you get in to the confusing cave, just go into either one of the first doors and keep going back into the door you came out of until you get to Rick.