# What is the ??? quest

Tags: browser-quest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the two 'hidden' achievements, and how do I get them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59442/what-are-the-two-hidden-achievements-and-how-do-i-get-them)

http://browserquest.mozilla.org/

There are 20 quests in the Browser Quest game by Mozilla, but the last quest is marked as ???, how does one complete or find this quest?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Go in the caves and if you go through caves enough times you reach a rick astley

Comment: This is the thanks we get for supporting their browser? A rickroll...